# itunes connect not showing build uploaded

Tags: ios

I have upload a new build yesterday and it gets uploaded successfully but .Until now it is not showing in itunes connect under prepared for submission section

Yedsterday build is uploaded using application loader and every thing went well .but now its been 18 hours i am not able to find the uploaded in itunesconnect

check the last screenshot

and One more thing in Version 1.2.1 there is 1.2.2 build is that any concern cehck the first screenshot

please do check screenshots attached  the following image showing the information about build live in app store
[image]
The following image is showing i created a new version on the app store

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check under Activity tab? It may still be processing.

Comment: And check your bundle identifier

Comment: YES,check the first screenshot

Comment: @CZ54 you mean Bundle ID if yes ,is same as the previous one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requested help form Apple .They reverted back with the message that the concern is with the build as need to add app entitlements for notification in the app .So i did the same and uploaded a new build which gets approved in three days